# put options in FTP client

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

Does the put command in FTP, "put local-file [remote-file ]", have some way to check if a file with the same name already exists in the specified directory on the remote machine so it doesn't store the local-file into the remote machine? If not, how does one go about doing that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [the ftp man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ftp), in particular the  `sunique` or `runique` command options. I haven't used these options myself, but they may help you accomplish what you are asking about.